# What are these accessories that came with my 1st gen iPod touch?

Tags: ipod-touch, ipod, accessories

I got these with my 1st gen iPod Touch, but I have never figured out how to use them? What are these for?

[image: iPod Accessories]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A dock adapter and a display stand.

http://www.appleinsider.com/articles/07/09/13/ipod_touch_unpacking_tour_and_first_look_photos.html